# Extra Indenting of Enumerate Environment

Tags: enumerate, indentation

I'd like to add extra space to my enumerate items. I currently use the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}

  \let\oldenumerate\enumerate
  \let\oldendenumerate\endenumerate
  \renewenvironment{enumerate}%
  % Beginning of environment
  {\begin{flushleft}
      \list{}{\rightmargin.0\textwidth\leftmargin3em}
    \item{}
      \oldenumerate
    }
    % end of environment
    {\oldendenumerate
      \endlist
    \end{flushleft}
  }

\begin{document}

Some text for reference.

\begin{enumerate}
\item The first level enumerate is indented properly.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item The second level is indented too much.
  \end{enumerate}
\item another first level item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

As I say in the MWE, the first level of the enumerate environment is exactly the way I want it. But the second level is indented just as much relative to the first level as the first is to the left margin. I want to avoid that. Instead, I want the second level to bear the same indenting relationship to the first level as in the normal enumerate environment.

Thanks!

Edit: I'm aware of the enumitem package, but for various reasons, I don't want to use it.

Comment: May I know for what purpose you redefined the `enumerate` environment?

Comment: @MadyYuvi I'm writing handouts for my classes where this indenting would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Use `enumitem`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=3em}

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{3em}{1pt}Some text for reference.

\begin{enumerate}
\item The first level enumerate is indented properly.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item The second level is indented too much.
  \end{enumerate}
\item another first level item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The rule shows that the indent is as requested.

[image]

The same is obtained with a lower level code.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\leftmargini}{3em}}

\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{3em}{1pt}Some text for reference.

\begin{enumerate}
\item The first level enumerate is indented properly.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item The second level is indented too much.
  \end{enumerate}
\item another first level item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a bunch of fairly specific further uses for enumerate environments, so I'd like to be able to make the modification without using the `enumitem` package.

Comment: @Bernhard The best way is to define appropriate environments, rather than changing `enumerate` in various ways. Anyway, I can't answer to what you don't ask.

Comment: Yes, that was a bad job on my part -- sorry about not explaining my constraints in the original post.

Comment: @Bernhard You can do it with lower level code, but I'm not sure what you're about.